# Functions differentiable on {$z \in \mathbb{C}: 0 < |z| < 1$}

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a past exam question from a Complex Analysis exam paper..

Prove or disprove that there exists a function $f$ differentiable on {$z \in \mathbb{C}: 0 <|z|<1$} such that

$(i) \displaystyle\lim_{z\rightarrow0}|f(z)|=\infty$

$(ii) \displaystyle\lim_{z\rightarrow0} zf(z)=0$

Im not really sure where to go with this type of question, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (ii) Says that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

Answer (score 2):

From (i) it follows that $f$ has a pole at the origin, i.e. $f$ can be written as $f(z) = z^{-m}g(z)$ for some positive integer $m$ and some analytic function $g$ with $g(0)\neq 0$. What does that tell you about (ii)?

Answer (score 2):

Another way to view this:
As $|f(z)|\to\infty$, there is $r>0$ such that $|f(z)|>1$ for $|z|<r$.
Then on $\{0<|z|<r\}$ we have holomorphic  $g\colon z\mapsto \frac1{f(z)}$ and as $\lim_{z\to0}g(z)=0$, it has a removable singularity. 
As (the extended) $g(0)=0$, we can write $g(z)=zh(z)$ with holomorphic $h$.
Now $zf(z)=\frac1{h(z)}$ either diverges (if $h(0)=0$) or converges $\to\frac{1}{h(z)}\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this function, I think it might work: $f(z)=z^{-1/2}$

Comment: It doesn't, see the intended region of definition.

Comment: Sorry @HagenvonEitzen, but I can not see the error. Can you please specify to me?

Comment: Your function is not holomorphic on the punctured disc.

Comment: The square root function has a branch cut; it's not differentiable in the disk, you have to remove a line along some axis, usually the negative real line.